# Rendering an array/object in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a code that works but I don't understand why I am returning an array of react components and they are still rendering in the page... how does this work?

```
render() {
        const boxes = Array.from({ length: this.props.numBoxes }).map(() => (
            <Box colors={this.props.allColors} />
        ));

        console.log(boxes);

        return <div className='BoxContainer'>{boxes}</div>;
```

Comment: Why wouldn't it? There's even a simple example [in the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#rendering-multiple-components).

Comment: You should read up on how React works. [`children` is either a single node or an array of nodes depending on if theres one or more children](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-cdn-6yjyo). When rendering an array of dynamic children you should also specify the `key` for them so react doesn't give you a warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each XML-like `JSX` tag is actually an object. As you can probably see in your `console.log` an array of objects, which React's internals use to render, monitor and update the components.
So simply `<div className="boxContainer"></div>` is an object in which's properties also contains it's children.

On the other hand, `boxes` results to an array of objects; you can replace `{boxes}` with:

```
{<Box colors={this.props.allColors} />
<Box colors={this.props.allColors} />
<Box colors={this.props.allColors} />
...
<Box colors={this.props.allColors} />
<Box colors={this.props.allColors} />}
```

for `JSX` `{boxes}` means put everything in `boxes` variable in the place I put `{boxes}` with two curly braces surrounding it.

You can suppose `boxes` is equivalent to:

```
<Box colors={this.props.allColors} />
<Box colors={this.props.allColors} />
<Box colors={this.props.allColors} />
...
<Box colors={this.props.allColors} />
<Box colors={this.props.allColors} />
```